# Visualizing Complex correlation matrix with R

Tags: r, data-visualization, correlation, r-corrplot

I have a code which create a matrix of correlation between several items and i want to visualize it in the best way, i tried to use corrplot function but i have a problem with it and can't understand any thing from it ,
this is my code with a sample of my data:

```
library(corrplot)
Orders<- structure(list(WHWorkOrderHeaderId = c(137413L, 137413L, 137413L, 
137413L, 137413L, 137413L, 137413L, 137413L, 137413L, 137413L, 
137413L, 137413L, 137429L, 137429L, 137429L, 137429L, 137429L, 
137429L, 137429L, 137429L, 137429L, 137260L, 137260L, 137260L, 
137260L, 137260L, 137260L, 137260L, 137260L, 137260L, 137260L, 
136729L, 136729L, 136729L, 136729L, 136729L, 136729L, 136729L, 
136729L, 136729L, 136729L, 136729L, 136729L, 136729L, 137902L, 
137902L, 137902L, 137902L, 137902L, 137902L, 137902L, 137974L, 
137974L, 138837L, 138837L, 138837L, 138837L, 138837L, 138837L, 
139424L, 139424L, 139424L, 139424L, 139424L, 139424L, 139424L, 
139424L, 139424L, 139642L, 139642L, 139642L, 139642L, 139642L, 
139642L, 139642L, 140676L, 140676L, 140676L, 140676L, 140676L, 
140676L, 140938L, 140938L, 140938L, 140938L, 140938L, 140938L, 
140938L, 140938L, 140938L, 140938L, 141302L, 141302L, 141302L, 
141302L, 141302L, 141302L, 138297L, 138297L, 138297L), OtherLangDescription = structure(c(17L, 
16L, 34L, 19L, 25L, 32L, 18L, 35L, 15L, 27L, 13L, 22L, 16L, 26L, 
5L, 20L, 19L, 14L, 29L, 35L, 27L, 17L, 16L, 30L, 26L, 5L, 19L, 
14L, 31L, 29L, 27L, 23L, 24L, 16L, 30L, 8L, 19L, 14L, 32L, 9L, 
31L, 35L, 27L, 21L, 24L, 30L, 26L, 5L, 14L, 32L, 31L, 26L, 5L, 
11L, 24L, 31L, 15L, 27L, 13L, 11L, 17L, 24L, 10L, 19L, 32L, 6L, 
31L, 33L, 23L, 11L, 17L, 4L, 10L, 19L, 31L, 23L, 11L, 4L, 10L, 
19L, 31L, 11L, 17L, 16L, 14L, 25L, 12L, 31L, 7L, 1L, 2L, 23L, 
3L, 35L, 15L, 27L, 28L, 17L, 24L, 16L), .Label = c(" Green Beans", 
"Baladi Cabbage", "Baladi Garlic", "Banati Grape", "Barshomi Figs", 
"Black Eggplant", "Cantaloupe", "Capsicum", "Carrot", "Chili Pepper", 
"Classic Eggplant", "Cooking Potato", "Coriander", "Cucumber", 
"Dill", "Flame Grape", "frying Potato", "Golden Onion", "Green pepper", 
"Hot Pepper", "Local Celery ", "Local Eggplant", "Local Lemon", 
"Local Pear", "Molokhia", "Momtaza Owais Mango", "Parsley", "Red Globe Grape", 
"Red Onion", "Superior Grape", "Tomato", "White Eggplant ", "Zaghlol Dates", 
"Zebdaya Mango", "Zucchini"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("WHWorkOrderHeaderId", 
"OtherLangDescription"), row.names = c(NA, -100L), class = "data.frame")

Orders$OtherLangDescription <- as.factor(Orders$OtherLangDescription)
orderList <- unique(Orders$OtherLangDescription) 
ListId <- lapply(orderList, function(x) subset(Orders, OtherLangDescription == x)$WHWorkOrderHeaderId) 
Initial_Tab <- lapply(ListId, function(x) subset(Orders, WHWorkOrderHeaderId %in% x)$OtherLangDescription) 
Correlation_Tab <- mapply(function(Product, ID) table(Product)/length(ID),
                          Initial_Tab, ListId) 
colnames(Correlation_Tab) <- orderList
cor_per<- round(Correlation_Tab*100,2)
#View(cor_per)
#plot cor matrix
corrplot(Correlation_Tab, tl.pos="lt", type="upper",        
         tl.col="black", tl.cex=0.6, tl.srt=45, is.corr = FALSE,
         addCoef.col="black", addCoefasPercent = TRUE,
         sig.level=0.50, insig = "blank")
```

Comment: Have you loaded the `corrplot` package? Or what exactly is your problem?

Comment: @Alex  yes i did

Comment: Then add it to your question in order to make your code reproducible. And state what your problem is and what you want to achieve.

Comment: Done, I want to represent the result in the simplest way,do you know another effective way to represent it?

Comment: I do not get an error with your code. Can you start a fresh R session and try it again?

Comment: I guess if you have many variables a plot is a good way to represent your results. However, I am no expert for this.

Comment: @Alex its worked after refreshing thanks, i'll try to plot it thanks

Comment: As a side note, due to the number of parameters you use (cf your last question), you should consider using `heatmap` from `plotly` as you can zoom in or get names by scrolling over the plot. Something like `plot_ly(x = rownames(Correlation_Tab), y = colnames(Correlation_Tab), z = Correlation_Tab, type = "heatmap")` should help you in your analysis.

Comment: @AshOfFire Thanks Ash very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try using network analyis. This is an example from "http://www.r-graph-gallery.com".

This is the example code:

```
# library
library(igraph)

# data
head(mtcars)

# Make a correlation matrix:
mat=cor(t(mtcars[,c(1,3:6)]))
# Keep only high correlations
mat[mat<0.995]=0

# Make an Igraph object from this matrix:
network=graph_from_adjacency_matrix( mat, weighted=T, mode="undirected", diag=F)

plot(network)
```

[image]

This would be the result:

You can adapt this example to yours, so you could better see the correlations.